# Sensor diagnostic tool won't run

Tags: windows, sdk, sensors

I 'm trying to run `sensordiagnostictool` on Windows 10 (version 1607). I have installed Windows SDK version 10.0.15063.468, but I'm unable to run the tool:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64>sensordiagnostictool.exe

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64>echo %errorlevel%
0
```

The tool won't show its GUI and simply terminates without any error code. Is there any way to make it work? Alternatively, is there another tool I could use to see which sensors I have and what values they output?

Comment: I also have this problem. According to the event viewer it is crashing due to an UnauthorizedAccessException. However I'm running it as administrator so that as far as I know it *should* have the requisite permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable location services.
Go to Settings -> Privacy -> Location and make sure it is turned on.

Comment: Thanks. I did have location permissions disabled.